# Mixed strategy approximations in a large game

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, game-theory

I'm new to game theory and was thinking about how to find mixed strategies for a particular game, and furthermore how to find good mixed strategy approximations of a game that may be too large to compute.

The setup goes something like this:

- We have a list of 2600 locations listed in descending order of size of location, say a100, b100, .., z100, a99, b99, .., z99, ... , a1, b1, .., z1 (so the first 26 locations are of size 100 etc)
- We cycle through locations in order and group them in to districts. Districts need to be of a certain size (lets say 100 for now but we can vary the threshold if we wish), a list of districts will look something like this then: {a100}, {b100}, .., {z100}, {a99,b99}, {c99,d99}, .., {y50,z50}, {a49,b49,c49},...,{a33,b33,c33,d33},....
- a user wants to visit a location, the user does not have any preference of which location to visit
- an adversary can control up to 10% the total size of the locations. If a user visits a district in which an adversary controls at least one of the locations then the user is compromised , otherwise the user is safe. (note: the total size of locations is 131300)

So my questions are:

Firstly how would I draw up the zero sum pay off matrix given the set up?

How do I find the mixed strategy for both user and adversary? Should I just randomly select a bunch of locations an adversary can control, find the mixed strategies in this subgame and then repeat this process many times? Is it feasible to find an exact solution over such a large matrix?

I'm not even sure whether it makes sense to have this as a one shot game or a sort of hide and seek kind of game?

I apologise for length of the post and the vague nature of my questions but I'm just starting out learning about game theory and couldn't find much literature relating to questions like the ones I posed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So A must choose which districts to occupy, and B must choose which district to visit, and the only thing that matters about a district is how much it would cost A to occupy it (out of A's allotment of 13130 units), which is common knowledge. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, so my assumption is that A will try and spread their allotment over as many districts as possible.

Comment: In that case, either A can cover all districts and win, or A can't cover all districts so B will choose the most expensive district and win. The actual optimal strategy is more subtle...

Comment: Yes it's finding the mixed strategy I'm confused about. I understand the psychology behind what is the best option for both players.